# Is it possible to know the list of email boxes from a domain?

Tags: email, dns

Is it possible to know the list of email boxes from a domain?
For example, domain domain.com. Need to know what are the boxes *@domain.com

Comment: You mean # of email accounts associated with a domain name?

Comment: I mean, what you need to get a list of email addresses from a domain.com. For example: info@domain.com, info2@domain.com, alex@domain.com e.t.c

Comment: If you're using Zimbra server, You can use this command `$ zmprov -l gaa domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is your own domain, no it is not possible.

Remotely trying to determine valid email boxes for a domain is something spammers are very very interested in. They might try dictionary attacks or brute force guessing of valid email addresses, but generally emails servers are built or configured to not give out that kind of information.